# Передать значение из EditText в переменную другого класса

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-edittext

Делаю простенькое приложение и застрял, помогите разобраться:

нужно из `EditText` передать значение в переменную `count` класса `RecyclerActivity`

вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button b_get;
    EditText et_joke;
   


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.b_get:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecyclerActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_joke = findViewById(R.id.et_joke);

        b_get = findViewById(R.id.b_get);
        b_get.setOnClickListener(this);}}
```

```
public class RecyclerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    public static int count;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей можно использовать [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru). В `MainActivity` при переходе в другую активность вытаскиваете текст из поля для ввода и конвертируете в Int:

```
String value= et_joke.getText().toString();
int finalValue=Integer.parseInt(value);
```

чтобы не возникло проблем при считывании текста в xml разметки активности в поле для ввода добавьте такой параметр:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

дальше `finalValue` добавляете к intent:

```
intent.putExtra("count", finalValue);
```

и в `RecyclerActivity` в `onCreate()` добавляете считывание:

```
int intValue = getIntent().getIntExtra("count", 0);
```

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: "Голосование недоступно для собственных сообщений"

Comment: На моем ответе имелось ввиду, там есть галка)))

Comment: стыдно то как)))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers